# Why is Firebase failing to retrieve logged in user in deployed GAE standard environment?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

I've got a single page (react+redux) app hosted on Google App Engine. After logging in, if I navigate to any but the root URL on the GAE deployed app, the Firebase auth check fails. This does not happen if I navigate directly to root from another tab, and everything works fine when testing on the local dev server, regardless of where I navigate.

The authentication check within the app is handled from within the root `App` component `componentDidMount()` method with `firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {...})`. I've added debug, and using the dev server, I get the 'authUser' no matter where I initially navigate. Hitting the deployed app, I get the user if I navigate to the root, and otherwise fail to get the `authUser`. Firebase is using the default `local` session management. Here's the code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { dispatches, history } = this.props;

  firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
    if (authUser) {
      authUser.getIdTokenResult().then(function(tokenInfo) {
        dispatches.signIn(authUser, tokenInfo)
      }).catch(function(error) {
        dispatches.setErrorMessage("Could not get token info; login invalidated.");
        dispatches.signOut()
        history.push(routes.LANDING);
      });
    }
    else {
      dispatches.signOut()
      history.push(routes.LANDING);
    }
  });
}
```

The auth check is going to:
`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=xxx`

If I diff the request and response headers between the successful request for the domain root and a non-root URL, the only difference is in the 'referer' which contains:

- `referer: https://xxx.appspot.com/` vs
- `referer: https://xxx.appspot.com/some_path`

And again, on the dev server, there's no problem in either case.

Not sure how relevant it is, but this is my handlers section from `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
  secure: always
  static_files: store-build/\1
  upload: store-build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$

- url: /static
  secure: always
  static_dir: store-build/static

- url: /api/.*
  secure: always
  script: _go_app

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  static_files: store-build/index.html
  upload: store-build/index.html
```

I've checked the Stackdriver GAE logs, which don't show anything of interest or unexpected. I have not found any Firebase-auth specific logs.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Can you share the code that's handling the auth process?

Comment: @Todomi I can, thanks. I've got a theory as to the problem. I'm working on an update to upload and test and will post results and/or code soon.

Comment: Great! hope it works, share the goodies if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My referer restrictions were misconfigured with a trailing slash.

In Google Cloud Console -> API & Services -> Credentials -> Firebase service account, the "Application restrictions" was set to to 'HTTP Referers' and I had the host domain specified as:

`https://xxx.appspot.com/`

The trailing slash was limiting it to that domain + root path. Changing it to:

`https://xxx.appspot.com`

Allowed referrers from anywhere in the domain. `https://xxx.appspot.com/*` also works.